# How do I launch a YouTube video in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

On my app I need a button, so when it's tapped a youtube video is launched.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

The iOS device has URL schemes that it recognize.  Build your youTube url like the following:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER
```

That will launch the youTube player on the device.

```
NSString *videoName = @"1JynBEX_kg8";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", videoName];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:url];
```

For more information on iOS URL Scheme [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need it so once the user click the button it launches into the video player and plays the video. All that does it launch it in safari on the device

Comment: Are you testing it on the simulator or in the actual device?. I believe it works differently.

Comment: In the simulator, maps & youTube are open in Safari.  On the device, it will open on their respective app.

Comment: Do all movie work, i just tested one and it says 'Movie cannot be played'

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Black Frog's answer, sharedInstance should be changed to sharedApplication like this:

```
NSString *videoName = @"1JynBEX_kg8";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", videoName];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:url];
```

Comment: williams, thanks.  I went ahead and corrected my answer with the correct class method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on that particular subject, but have you checked in the youTube developper kits. I think there is some Cocoa stuffs...

Another way is to create a webview that you point to a webpage containing only your video.
I guess it is a working solution.